# How to refactor multiple if statement with multiple string conditions inside?

Tags: .net, refactoring

I'm trying to refactor this code, I tought about creating a dictionary with the values, but I'm not sure.

```
String version "1.0";

if (version.Equals("1.0.0(beta)") || version.Equals("1.0.0(beta2)") || version.Equals("1.0.0(beta3)") || version.Equals("1.0.0"))
            {
                newVersion= executionType.Equals("Install") ? "2.0.0(beta)" : "1.0.0(beta)";
            }
            else if(version.Equals("3.0.0(beta)") || version.Equals("3.0.0(beta2)") || version.Equals("3.0.0(beta3)") || version.Equals("3.0.0"))
            {
                newVersion= executionType.Equals("Install") ? "4.0.0(beta)" : "3.0.0(beta)";
            }
            else if (version.Equals("5.0.0(beta)") || version.Equals("5.0.0(beta2)") || version.Equals("5.0.0(beta3)") || version.Equals("5.0.0" || version.Equals("5.0.0.b"))
            {
                newVersion= executionType.Equals("Install") ? "6.0.0(beta)" : "5.0.0(beta)";
            }
            else if(same){
newVersion = same;
```

Like 7 else if total.
I have to do this with .NET 2.0.

Comment: use `switch` to handle your conditions, for the `||` you can use `switch fallthrough` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement

Comment: If I use switch, I would have to put switch(version) and do the comparision of the value with the same multiple strings in the same line, isn´t it the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For .NET2.0 I'm afraid you have to stick with `switch`:

```
switch(version)
{
    case "1.0.0(beta)":
    case "1.0.0(beta2)":
    case "1.0.0(beta3)":
    case "1.0.0":                
        newVersion = executionType.Equals("Install") ? "2.0.0(beta)" : "1.0.0(beta)";
        break;
    case "3.0.0(beta)":
    case "3.0.0(beta2)":
    case "3.0.0(beta3)":
    case "3.0.0":
        newVersion= executionType.Equals("Install") ? "4.0.0(beta)" : "3.0.0(beta)";
        break;
    case "5.0.0(beta)":
    case "5.0.0(beta2)":
    case "5.0.0(beta3)":
    case "5.0.0":
    case "5.0.0.b":
        newVersion= executionType.Equals("Install") ? "6.0.0(beta)" : "5.0.0(beta)";
        break;
}
```

But now seeing these "cases" you can see similarities better. I don't know the rest of your values, but these cases look like you can try this:

```
switch(version.SubString(0, 5)) // only test first 5 characters
{
    case "1.0.0":
        newVersion = executionType.Equals("Install") ? "2.0.0(beta)" : "1.0.0(beta)";
        break;
    case "3.0.0":
        newVersion= executionType.Equals("Install") ? "4.0.0(beta)" : "3.0.0(beta)";
        break;
    case "5.0.0":
        newVersion= executionType.Equals("Install") ? "6.0.0(beta)" : "5.0.0(beta)";
        break;
}
```

and therefor indeed use two dictionaries:

```
Dictionary<string, string> versionsForInstall = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"1.0.0", "2.0.0(beta)"},
    {"3.0.0", "4.0.0(beta)"},
    {"5.0.0", "6.0.0(beta)"}
};
Dictionary<string, string> versionsForOther = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"1.0.0", "1.0.0(beta)"},
    {"3.0.0", "3.0.0(beta)"},
    {"5.0.0", "5.0.0(beta)"}
};
```

And then do

```
newVersion = executionType.Equals("Install") 
             ? versionsForInstall[version.SubString(0,5)]
             : versionsForOther[version.SubString(0,5)];
```

Comment: nice and clean solution.  The only thing I would add is checking for the version not existing in the dictionary at all, which I think is represented in the "same" case in the original question

Comment: @KyleBurns you're right that this code lacks error handling like a version not in the dictionary, but I don't know the real code so no idea what is the best error handling here. the "same" case in OP's example is afaik a placeholder for more `if` statements. `if (same) newVersion = same` is not valid c# when `newVersion` is a `string`.

Answer (score 0):

there is a lot that could be done refactoring here, but the first step I would take would be to focus on all of the || operators.  If I see more than one (and even one sometimes pushes it) || or && in an evaluation, it smells like something that will attract maintenance confusion and later bugs.  I would find it much easier to read:

```
if(IsV1Variant(version))
{
  ...
}
else if(IsV2Variant(version))
{
  ...
}
```

It also looks in this case like a StartsWith comparison could simplify the logic and reduce the risk of values not falling through the cracks

Answer (score 0):

Use a switch similar to this

```
switch (version)
{
  case "1.0.0(beta)":
  case "1.0.0(beta2)":
  case "1.0.0(beta3)":
  case "1.0.0(beta)":
    newVersion= executionType.Equals("Install") ? "2.0.0(beta)" : "1.0.0(beta)";
    break;

  case "3.0.0(beta)":
  case "3.0.0(beta2)":
  case "3.0.0(beta3)":
  case "3.0.0":
    newVersion= executionType.Equals("Install") ? "4.0.0(beta)" : "3.0.0(beta)";
    break;

  case "5.0.0(beta)":
  case "5.0.0(beta2)":
  case "5.0.0":
  case "5.0.0.b":
    newVersion= executionType.Equals("Install") ? "6.0.0(beta)" : "5.0.0(beta)";
    break;
}
```

Do not be afraid to write a lots of lines. The CLS will optimize your code!